# Undertermined Javascript Error

Tags: javascript

I have implemented the .NET Login functionality, and I am receiving a JavaScript Error whenever a User clicks on the Log-In Anchor Button to reach the Login.aspx.

This Anchor Menu Button is part of the CSS Menu which is defined within the Master Page.

When I run this locally, the error indicates:

> 'ddmegamenu' is undefined

However this script is defined within the MasterPage:

All of the sub-pages can see this script including the `Login.aspx`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ddmegamenu.docinit({
        menuid: 'solidmenu',
        dur: 200 //<--no comma after last setting
    })
</script>
```

Here is the development site: http://www.virtualpetstore.com

The `Login.aspx` is within a seperate Account Directory, but I don't think this should be a problem.

If anyone can see this issue, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're not properly referencing the JS files on the Login.aspx page. This is what the console says (in addition to the error that you posted):

```
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/jquery-1.5.min.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/jquery-ui.min.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/jquery.serialScroll-min.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/ddmegamenu.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/jquery.simplemodal.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/jquery.cycle.min.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/jquery.actual.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.virtualpetstore.com/Account/js/contact.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Ensure that your JS files are being loaded and your error will most likely disappear.

**Hint:** Your script tags should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ddmegamenu.js"></script>
```

Comment: And while doing that, don't include jQuery twice.

Comment: @James Hill I changed all of the script tags with: src="/js/ddmegamenu.js Now I don't receive the fatal error as before indicating 'ddmegamenu' is undefined

however at the bottom of all of every page it indicates: "done but with errors on the page" you can see this on the dev site: http://www.virtualpetstore.com

Comment: @Paul, I just checked out the site and I'm not seeing any errors. Did my solution work for you?

Comment: @JamesHill yes your solution did work.  At the bottom of the page in the status bar, it indicates "done but with errors"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, on Account/Login.aspx you try to include Account/js/ddmegamenu.js
but you need on this url /js/ddmegamenu.js